# Mounting devices fails, left at initramfs on boot

Tags: crash

My pc crashed and it gets a weird text when i try to start up my pc and the text keeps there and My pc doesn't start anymore:

```
mount: mounting /dev/disc/by-uud/08782e-c42e-b26f-dd0b51c13446 on /root
failed: Invalid argument 
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: no such file or directory 
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: no such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: no such file or directory 
target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
no init found. Try passing init= bootrag.

BusyBox v1.21.1 (ubuntu 1:1.21.0-ubuntu1) built-in shell  (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

(Initframs)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Maybe you should contact a propper mechanic… it should be windows problem. Why did it crashed?

Answer (score 0):

Something that called the `mount` command passed an invalid argument when it tried to mount your primary root filesystem...This could be due to a lot of reasons...but first what's the content of your fstab?

If you need to boot into your OS immediately... you can try

```
mount -t (YOUR_FS_TYPE) /dev/disc/by-uud/08782e-c42e-b26f-dd0b51c13446 /root
# and then
exit
```

and see what happens, then run

```
update-initramfs
```

when you've booted into Ubuntu to see if it goes away.

Comment: Uhm joshumax im pretty nooby with pc's.... how can i actually know what my FS type is?

Comment: @ikkesklerk It's probably either ext3 or ext4...if that doesn't work you could try running `mount` without the `-t` option

Comment: Aww i probbaly have to ask a pro. Because when i try to do that it sais "ed: no such file or directory"